# "text-align-last: justify" is not working with pdf generated by wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css

I am genrating Pdf using wkhtmltopdf so ,"text-align-last: justify" is 
  not working in pdf .Any one help me for this issue.

```
<p style="text-align:justify;text-align-last: justify;">*pginf* 
Important Information Prior to Travelling to Brazil |b|</p>
```

Comment: You could try if the hack that emulates this using a pseudo element works in that situation, https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/one-line-justified-text-design/

Answer (score -1):

Text-align help you to Stretches the lines and break in same line every time, I can figure out from your code you have less amount of paragraph text. Add more text then you can find out the result how text-align:justify work.

```
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. 
Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</p>

p{
  text-align:justify; 
}
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is that I want to Stretche this text in full width of pdf ".text-align-last: justify" is working in html but in pdf it is not working.